# How to modify ~/.ssh folder & files in windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, directory, home-directory

I feel like I am missing some fundamental concept as to how the .ssh directory works in windows.  I have had no issues when working in OSX/Linux like I am having now.  My end goal is simply to move my existing ssh key into the default ~/.ssh directory, and update the config if I so choose (you know, normal ssh key related tasks).

However, any time I have tried to move my existing SSH key over to the ~/.ssh directory, or open it, or even create a config file I just get the following error (in either gitbash, puttygen, etc...):

Puttygen (saving the key to disk):

```
Overwrite existing file C:\Users\me\.ssh?
```

or in gitbash (attempting to do anything, including just create the config file):

```
touch: creating `/c/Users/me/.ssh/config': No such file or directory

cd ~/.ssh

sh.exe": cd: /c/Users/me/.ssh: Not a directory
```

What am I missing/not understanding?

Kind Regards,
u353

Comment: "dot" directories are a unixism that doesn't work well in Windows. e.g. it's impossible to directly create a ".dir" in Explorer (you get "You must type a filename"). try creating the relevant directories yourself using a cmd prompt and try again.

Comment: Thanks @Marc B -  I guess what I'm wondering is are there any key properties about using the dot configuration folder that won't translate over to my using ssh with a plan-ol-windows /ssh/ directory?  Just worried this is somehow one day not going to do something I expect - simply because it's not a dot file, and not in linux..  ie. a program looks for the default location ~/.ssh/ and it's not there.

Comment: well, the errors would suggest that .ssh is a file, not a directory. puttygen's trying to overwrite it as a file, and gitbash is trying to treat it as a dir.

Comment: So how do I get the same functionality of the ~/.ssh folder in windows so I can update/add/modify ssh settings and use it to automatically connect to remote hosts that have my public key?

Comment: So even at the time of this post, I had puttygen, pageant, and plink installed and running with a passphrase setup and working just fine.  What I didn't know was that I needed to add a value for GIT_SSH in my env var's to point to plink.exe...

To make matters worse, GitBash HATES good passwords (apparently), and won't accept it when trying to authenticate.  I've checked & rechecked my passphrase.  Still a no go.  Sent an email to Github hoping for the best.

Answer (score -27, accepted):

This isn't supported as Windows doesn't recognize dot files as directories.

Comment: Simply not true

Answer (score 35):

This answer for **Windows environment**:

At the beginning, Windows didn't have `.ssh` folder.
Create an ssh key file pair like this (`ssh-keygen` is nowadays a native Windows command, that comes with Windows 10+11):

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"` (**must run your terminal as administrator**).

Your `is_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files will be placed under `C:\Users\your_username\`

So, you need to create the folder `C:\Users\your_username\.ssh` then copy your ssh files (the extensionless private key and the public key ending in `.pub`) to there.

You also have to create file `C:\Users\your_username\.ssh\config` and edit it for the first time.

Next ssh will be placed in the `.ssh` folder automatically.

**Note: `~/` under Linux is the equivalent of `C:\Users\your_username\` on Windows**

Answer (score 8):

I have created and regularly use a ".ssh" directory on Windows 7; as mentioned in the above comments, Windows Explorer doesn't support them, or more specifically, the error-checking in Windows Explorer does not allow you to give a file name that starts with a period. That same restriction does not exist in the command prompt or powershell.

Also, as mentioned above, it appears you have a file called ".ssh" in your home directory, which must be removed before you can create a folder named ".ssh".

Once such a folder exists, you can open it and change/create files in it using Windows Explorer; it just won't let you name a folder/file ".ssh" directly.

Gitbash should directly allow you to run "rm .ssh" and "mkdir .ssh", at which point everything else should work.

Answer (score 5):

It is quite possible to add a `.` in the beginning of a directories name using File Explorer, it can be easily done by adding a `.` at the end of the directory name as well. For example:

To create a directory named `.shh`, just add the name as `.ssh.` and it will be created without any error.

And as @Bryson mentioned, this can be done from the cli as well, without appending a `.` at the end.

Answer (score 5):

Coming to this in 2018, given that on Windows 10 you have the Optional Feature *OpenSSH client* installed it appears that on Windows a `.ssh` folder is created for you under `C:\Users\<your_username>\.ssh`

This is a feature that allows you to use PowerShell to SSH into remote hosts, and seems to be pretty similar in usage to the Linux/Unix equivalent. It was already installed for me when I setup my computer, but you can read the following for how to verify it's installed or install it:

You can check if it's installed by going to Settings -> Manage Optional Features, and then checking if you see OpenSSH in the list. If it is then your .ssh folder is probably in your home directory `C:\Users\<your_username>\.ssh`. If you need to install it then click "Add a feature", locate OpenSSH Client, click it and click install to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Use git bash on windows
go to home directory as

`$ cd`

then to check .ssh folder on home directory use

```
$ ls -A
```

you will be able to see a ./ssh folder there

```
$ cd ./ssh
$ ls
```

you will be able to see the config files if exists

To transfer any key-pair or any files to this folder use below command
First to that directory in which you already have key-pair

```
$ cp name_of_key-pair_file.pem ~/.ssh/
```

Comment: Windows powershell `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` is the command. `ls` is not a windows command.

Comment: `ls` does not run in PowerShell, that why in my answer I had mentioned using git bash or MingW

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to generate SSH files, all you need to do is run this command:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Once you did, **.ssh folder** will be generated in this path:

```
C:\Users\your_username\
```

For checking what files are in .ssh folder you can easily run this command:

```
ls ~/.ssh
```

with this above command, you can see all your ssh files which would be like this:

```
id_rsa   id-rsa.pub
```

*Please note that:*

**id_rsa** : It's a private file and
**id-rsa.pub** : It's a public file

so, if you like to see inside of that file or whatever you like just type this command :

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I used git batsh console